# How to get XDG variables with sudo?

Tags: linux, sudo

I need to retrieve $XDG_CONFIG_HOME, $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR and $XDG_DATA_HOME of all users.
I try with:

```
sudo -Eiu user printenv | grep XDG_CONFIG_HOME
```

But I get nothing.

If I log on with the user account, the simple command:

```
printenv | grep XDG_CONFIG_HOME
```

Works fine.

How do I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TLDR, these variables are not available in the `sudo` case, and some can even not be set **at all** in the standard login case.

On my linux system (debian 8) some of the `XDG` variables are defined when the user's session is initialized with the pam module `pam_systemd`. The variables defined to be initialised at that point are documented in the man page, but include `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR`.

This module is only loaded in the login cases - i.e. I need to ssh to the system, or login via the console/gui to get the user session to initialize via the `pam_systemd` module.

This module is not loaded in the `su` or the `sudo` cases.

As a result, when you do a `sudo` to emulate a user this variable is not set.

Other `XDG` variables are only applicable when the user is actually logged in at the GUI. I don't get these variable set on the GUI that I use, but [the docs for XDG variables](http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/latest/ar01s03.html) specify what they are supposed to default to if they're not set. The default value for `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` is `$HOME/.config`,  and the default value for `XDG_DATA_HOME` is `$HOME/.local/share`.

So you should only expect these variables to be set in the interactive login case, and not via the non-interactive case - `sudo` would be effectively designated as a non-interactive case, even though you can do interactive things with it.

These values are very much templated - e.g. the `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` on my system is `/var/run/UID`, and, per the man page, does not survive after my last logout; so it's not a place to put permanent files.

Unless you, as a user change these values, I would expect the defaults that are specified in the XDG documentation, [the KDE compliance](https://userbase.kde.org/KDE_System_Administration/Environment_Variables#freedesktop.org_Compliance) pages to be the ones that are used. There are probably others, but I just picked the KDE compliance one as it calls it out in the systems admin guide.

Comment: It's not too long that's great because I understood now why I do not have the same result by connecting with ssh, sudo or interactive method. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are several parts to isolating all general users (non-system accounts) on a Linux box. For your purpose, the easiest is probably reading all users into an array, and then looking at the XDG config for each. A quick bash script for this purpose is:

```
#!/bin/bash

uarray=( $(awk -F':' -v "limit=$(grep "^UID_MIN" /etc/login.defs | sed -e 's/UID_MIN\s*//')" '{ if ( $3 >= limit ) print $1}' /etc/passwd) ) 

for i in "${uarray[@]}"; do
    printf "\nXDG Config for user:  %s\n\n" "$i"
    sudo -Eiu $i printenv | grep XDG
done
```

That will print all XDG environment variables for each user with a brief header to identify whose it is. If you would prefer it all in one line:

```
for i in $(awk -F':' -v "limit=$(grep "^UID_MIN" /etc/login.defs | sed -e 's/UID_MIN\s*//')" '{ if ( $3 >= limit ) print $1}' /etc/passwd); do printf "\nXDG Config for user:  %s\n\n" "$i"; sudo -Eiu $i printenv | grep XDG; done
```

You can limit or change which XDG environment variables are selected by narrowing the argument for `grep`.

Comment: The problem he's having is that **none** of the XDG variables are set in the sudo case.

Comment: Either that or he is using `user` instead of each individual user name. Another possibility is the XDG config is loaded on desktop start, and then as you say, unavailable for some users not logged in.

Comment: To retrieve the list of users in one line solution is perfect. Adopted. Thank you.